# Can not find model class in module application

Tags: module, zend-framework

I'm new in Zend, i had defined in my application.ini some lines to use multiple db.

```
resources.multidb.sitgm.adapter = "pdo_pgsql"
resources.multidb.sitgm.host = "localhost"
resources.multidb.sitgm.username = "postgres"
resources.multidb.sitgm.password = "pass"
resources.multidb.sitgm.dbname = "mydb"
resources.multidb.sitgm.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

In my APPLICATION Bootstrap i have a function:

```
public function _initDbRegistry()
{
    $this->_application->bootstrap('multidb');
    $multidb = $this->_application->getPluginResource('multidb');
    Zend_Registry::set('db_sitgm', $multidb->getDb('sitgm'));
}
```

But when i had migrated to module squema, i have a default module, i added another DEFAULT Bootstrap.

```
class Default_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
public function _initDbRegistry()
{
   //Do i must add something here to access application DB conf like app bootstrap????
}
}
```

In this point How i can call the application config beacuse i am getting an error in my default model class which can not find it.

```
class Default_Model_Base {
    protected $db;
    public $sql="";
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = Zend_Registry::get("db_sitgm");  //HERE I GOT THE ERROR
       $this->db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
    } 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to define the `_initDbRegistry` in your module bootstrap as well. You can leave it in your application `Bootstrap.php`